# How can i get the points coordinates from text file with using Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I would like get points coordinates from text file. Text file is too long. You can find a sample at below.

SAMPLE TEXT

POINTS Data

$$

```
          ID         X           Y       Z
POINTS         1        -5.15315     0.0     0.0

POINTS         2        -5.15315     0.0     0.0

POINTS         3             0.0   100.0     0.0

POINTS         4           100.0   100.0     0.0

POINTS         5           100.0     0.0     0.0

POINTS         6           100.0 105.325   200.0

POINTS         7           100.0   100.0   200.0

POINTS         8        -2.13-14   100.0     0.0

POINTS         9           100.0-1.42-14     0.0

POINTS        10        1.421-14-2.84-14     0.0

POINTS        11        -2.13-14   100.0     0.0
```

$$
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------$
$$             Group Definitions                                                $
$$------------------------------------------------------------------------------$

Firstly i am not good at coding if you show me simply, i will be appreciated.

The aim is to get points id and coordinates.

1. 1-read all the text file.

   2-find the text length(row counts)

   3-Create a for loop which starts 0 to (row counts)

   4-detect the lines which starts with "POINTS" ( I thought to use
   mid(lines(i)),0,5)="POINTS")

   5-Then use if mid(lines(i)),0,5)="POINTS" then
   mid(lines(i)),25,33)=cord(i)

   6-Finally write this array to a text file.

The code i tried to this however it fails.

I am using visual studio 2019.
Best regards

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myfilepath, test, test1, test2, i, strline

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        myfilepath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
    Dim cordx()
    Dim cordy()
    Dim cordz()

    Dim satirlar = IO.File.ReadAllLines(myfilepath).Length
    MsgBox(satirlar)
    Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(myfilepath).ToList
    For i = 0 To satirlar
        If lines(i).ToLower.StartsWith("points") Then
            cordx(i) = Mid(lines(i), 25, 33)
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox(cordx)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: When you say, your code above fails, what exactly do you mean by fails?  Get an exception of unexpected output?

Comment: I think I asked this question the first time you posted this question. In the first version it appeared that the X,y,Z fields were fixed width. In this version it appears they delimited by a space but several lines do not have 3 coordinates separated by a space. We need some rules about  how to determine what is X, Y. and Z.

Comment: hi Mary you are right , the fields are fixed,i edited

Comment: @SeçkinUslu You write "The aim is to get points id and coordinates," but the code in the question does not show anything to do with the id. Is the id required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's work through and make your code a bit simpler:

```vb
    'please call your button something better than Button1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'Dim stuff near to where it's used, not at the top of a method
        'Dim myfilepath, test, test1, test2, i, strline

        'I usually invert this check and return if it's not OK - stops the method code
        'from proceeding if the user didn't want it. Name your OpenFileDialog something
        'better than OpenFileDialog1
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.OK Then Return

        'you make some empty arrays here but these won't be that useful (so i'll remove them)
        'because you try to access them before you gave them a length, resulting in an exception
        'Dim cordx()
        'Dim cordy()
        'Dim cordz()

        'I'm going to use a named ValueTuple instead; it's a small class that holds 3 values, 
        'and means I don't have to create a struct or class for it. Because I need
        'to store multiple of them I'll use a List(Of ...) where ... is the named valuetuple:
        Dim coords As New List(Of (XCoord As Double, YCoord As Double, ZCoord As Double))

        'read the file once, and store the lines. Your code reads the whole file just to find out how many
        'lines there are, then reads it again - a waste
        'Dim satirlar = IO.File.ReadAllLines(myfilepath).Length

        'note I just got the name from the OpenFileDialog1 - no need to store it in
        'another variable. Don't need to ToList() either - ReadAllLines returns an array
        Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.Filename)

        'Don't need to ToList() either - ReadAllLines returns an array
        'Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(myfilepath).ToList

        'For Each loop is nicer to read than one using i. You don't need random access to
        'the array here, so use a ForEach
        'For i = 0 To satirlar
        For Each line In lines

            If line.ToLower().StartsWith("points") Then

                'Don't use Mid - that's old VB6 nomenclature. Use Substring
                Dim x = line.Substring(24, 8)
                Dim y = line.Substring(32, 8)
                Dim z = line.Substring(40, 8)

                'what kind of number is -2.13-14 supposed to be??? fix it here:
                x = x.Replace("-14", "")
                y = y.Replace("-14", "")
                z = z.Replace("-14", "")


                'this makes a named ValueTuple. You need to be using .net 4.7.2 or use Nuget to Install the System.ValueTuple 
                Dim t = (XCoord:=Convert.ToDouble(x), YCoord:=Convert.ToDouble(x), ZCoord:=Convert.ToDouble(z))

                'add our parsed coordinates to the list
                coords.Add(t)

            End If
        Next

        'now you say you want to write it to a file. OK, lets make a simple CSV
        'this uses LINQ to visit every element in the coords list 
        'and convert from a ValueTuple of 3 doubles, to a string like 1.0,2.0,3.3
        Dim newFileLines = coords.Select(Function(c) $"{c.XCoord},{c.YCoord},{c.ZCoord}").ToArray()

        'write the file back to a new file alongside the original, but with a coords.csv extension
        IO.File.WriteAllLines(IO.Path.ChangeExtension(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, "coords.csv"), newFileLines)


    End Sub
```

Actually, if all you're gonna do is write them to file again we can skip the double conversion and other such stuff (valuetuples etc):

```vb
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.OK Then Return

        Dim newLines = New List(Of String)

        For Each line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.Filename)

            If line.ToLower().StartsWith("points") Then

                Dim x = line.Substring(24, 8)
                Dim y = line.Substring(32, 8)
                Dim z = line.Substring(40, 8)

                newLines.Add($"{x},{y},{z}")

            End If
        Next
        IO.File.WriteAllLines(IO.Path.ChangeExtension(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, "coords.csv"), newLines)


    End Sub
```

Comment: Caius thanks for your effoct . Now i understand it well. 
Whenever i open visual studio, i remind you with my grateful feelings.
If you have time could you please show me the a guideline, website or book to learn VB better.
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Base on your edit, the fields in your text file are fixed width. The text file I used for testing looks like this.

```
POINTS         1        -5.15315     0.0     0.0

POINTS         2        -5.15315     0.0     0.0

POINTS         3             0.0   100.0     0.0

POINTS         4           100.0   100.0     0.0

POINTS         5           100.0     0.0     0.0

POINTS         6           100.0 105.325   200.0

POINTS         7           100.0   100.0   200.0

POINTS         8        -2.13-14   100.0     0.0

POINTS         9           100.0-1.42-14     0.0

POINTS        10        1.421-14-2.84-14     0.0

POINTS        11        -2.13-14   100.0     0.0
```

I created a simple class for your data. The serializable attribute is important if you want to save the data.

```
<Serializable>
Public Class Coordinates
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property CordX As String
    Public Property CordY As String
    Public Property CordZ As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"ID {ID} X:{CordX}  Y:{CordY}  Z:{CordZ}"
    End Function

End Class
```

In the Form.Load I filled the a list of coordinates form either the fixed width text file or the xml data. The List is declared at the Form level and can be accessed from any method in the form. The data is displayed in a DataGridView by setting the list as the .DataSource.

```
Private CoordinateList As New List(Of Coordinates)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If File.Exists("coordinates.xml") Then
        FillCoordinateListFromXML()
    Else
        FillCoordinatesListFromTextFile()
    End If
    DataGridView1.DataSource = CoordinateList
End Sub
```

One of the following methods is called to accomplish this.

```
Private Sub FillCoordinatesListFromTextFile()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("coordinates.txt")
    For Each line In lines
        If line.StartsWith("POINTS") Then
            Dim crd As New Coordinates
            'Indexes are zero based
            'Substring(startIndex, Length)
            crd.ID = CInt(line.Substring(7, 9).Trim)
            crd.CordX = line.Substring(16, 16).Trim
            crd.CordY = line.Substring(32, 8).Trim
            crd.CordZ = line.Substring(40).Trim
            CoordinateList.Add(crd)
        End If
    Next
    'Just for testing
    For Each cord In CoordinateList
        Debug.Print(cord.ToString)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FillCoordinateListFromXML()
    Dim serial As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Coordinates)))
    Using fs As New FileStream("coordinates.xml", FileMode.Open)
        CoordinateList = DirectCast(serial.Deserialize(fs), List(Of Coordinates))
    End Using
    'Just for testing
    For Each item In CoordinateList
        Debug.Print(item.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is the method to save the data to an xml file. An XML file is all text and human readable in Notepad.

```
Private Sub SaveCoordinatesList()
    Dim serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Coordinates)))
    Using writer As New StreamWriter("coordinates.xml")
        serializer.Serialize(writer, CoordinateList)
    End Using
End Sub
```

The resulting xml file created from the list is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfCoordinates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <CordX>-5.15315</CordX>
    <CordY>0.0</CordY>
    <CordZ>0.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <CordX>-5.15315</CordX>
    <CordY>0.0</CordY>
    <CordZ>0.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <CordX>0.0</CordX>
    <CordY>100.0</CordY>
    <CordZ>0.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <CordX>100.0</CordX>
    <CordY>100.0</CordY>
    <CordZ>0.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <CordX>100.0</CordX>
    <CordY>0.0</CordY>
    <CordZ>0.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>6</ID>
    <CordX>100.0</CordX>
    <CordY>105.325</CordY>
    <CordZ>200.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>7</ID>
    <CordX>100.0</CordX>
    <CordY>100.0</CordY>
    <CordZ>200.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>8</ID>
    <CordX>-2.13-14</CordX>
    <CordY>100.0</CordY>
    <CordZ>0.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>9</ID>
    <CordX>100.0</CordX>
    <CordY>-1.42-14</CordY>
    <CordZ>0.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>10</ID>
    <CordX>1.421-14</CordX>
    <CordY>-2.84-14</CordY>
    <CordZ>0.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
  <Coordinates>
    <ID>11</ID>
    <CordX>-2.13-14</CordX>
    <CordY>100.0</CordY>
    <CordZ>0.0</CordZ>
  </Coordinates>
</ArrayOfCoordinates>
```

You can select a single set of coordiantes with this Function and the view any of its properties. This is using a bit of Link magic.

```
Private Function GetCoordinateByID(Id As Integer) As Coordinates
    Dim crd = (From c In CoordinateList
               Where c.ID = Id
               Select c).FirstOrDefault
    Return crd
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim crd = GetCoordinateByID(2)
    MessageBox.Show($"The X coordiante is {crd.CordX}")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mary for your contrubitions.
I have a problem like this
'code' Dim x = line.Substring(41, 8)

Comment: Microsoft documentation for Substring can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8  Basicly, it returns a new string x, starting at the zero based index 41 and containing 8 characters from the string called line.

Comment: *createnode x y z 0 0 0
*createmarklast nodes 1 
*renumbersolverid nodes 1 id  1 0 0 0 0 0

Sorry to disturb you again, at the end of the the day i would like to create a text file above. with your contrubitons , ı am able to create all of the three lines. However i have a lot of points and for each points i would like to write these three lines to txt file. If you have time could you please show me how to insert these three lines (for every point) with for loop ( or any method) . 
Regards

Comment: As a sample
`*createnode   100.0     0.0    500.0 0 0 0
*createmarklast nodes 1 
*renumbersolverid nodes 1 id  1 0 0 0 0 0
*createnode   100.0    50.0    500.0 0 0 0
*createmarklast nodes 1 
*renumbersolverid nodes 1 id  1 0 0 0 0 0
*createnode   100.0   100.0    500.0 0 0 0
*createmarklast nodes 1 
*renumbersolverid nodes 1 id  1 0 0 0 0 0
*createnode   100.0   150.0    500.0 0 0 0
*createmarklast nodes 1 
*renumbersolverid nodes 1 id  1 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: I am not sure where the createnode, renumbersolveid nodes, coreatemarklast nodes come from. I don't see any of that in your original text file sample. I have added my source file and the xml file it produced to my answer. Since you used a new set of numbers in your sample, I am not sure what is what. Have you added a DataGridView to your Form? Just to see what the list collected?